# Causative verbs: to have/get something done

Tags: verbs

Is it the same things whether I use the auxiliar verb "to have" or the verb "to get" in these causative structures? Are there any difference here? I need someone to clarify this doubt to me:

I have/get my watch fixed. (present positive present)

I don't have/get my watch fixed. (negative present tense)

Do I have/get my watch fixed? (interrogative positive present tense)

Do I not have/get my watch fixed? (interrogative negative present tense)

I had/got my hair cut. simple. (simple positive past tense)

i didn't have/ get my hair cut. (simple negative past tense)

Did I have/get my hair cut simple (interrogative affirmative tense)

Did I not have/get my hair cut? (simple interrogative negative tense)

i will have/ get my house repaired. (Future positive tense)

I will not have/ get my house repaired.  (future negative tense)

Will I have/get my house repaired? future interrogative positive tense

Will I not have/get my house repaired? (future interrogative negative tense)

I am going to have/get my tasks done (planned future tense)

I am not going  to have/get my tasks done

Am I not going to have/get my tasks done?

Am I GOING TO HAVE/get MY TASKS DONE?

I have had/got my car washed. (present perfect tense)

I have not had/ got my car washed. (present perfect negative tense)

Have I not had/ got my car washed? (present perfect interrogative tense)

Have I had/got my car washed? (present perfect interrogative tense)

I am having/getting a new house built. (present continuous tense)

I am not having/ getting a new house built. (present negative continuous tense)

Am I having/ getting a new house built? (present continuous interrogative tense)

Am I not having/getting a new house? (present negative continuous tense)

One more thing: How is the imperative or exclamative mood for this structure (causative verb[to have something done])?

Comment: See this for more information: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/83013/211575. The difference is subtle, but it's there. As an aside, this should probably be split into multiple questions. Just at a quick glance, I see some pairs that would require separate, pair-specific responses.